# Get list of Concurrent processes in Execution

Tags: apex, callout, concurrency

We are getting "Concurrent Requests Limit Exceeded." in our production org . Some transactions in our ORG require to much time as they involve callouts to external systems. Thus taking more than 5 seconds in execution and leading into concurrency.

Is there a way in which we can find number of processes in execution that have taken more than 5 seconds(i.e they are currently running and taking lot of time) so we can postpone newly created transactions for some time thus avoiding hitting concurrency request limits.

Comment: You may have already seen this but in case you have not [Designing Force.com Applications That Avoid Hitting Concurrent Request Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/05/force-com-concurrent-request-limits.html).

Comment: Yes, i have seen this. Unfortunately the third party external systems don't support the other mechanisms as said in the documentation.  Hence we are forced to do something from SFDC end. If by someway we could get the list of long running processes, we can prevent ours from being started(aka postponing) to get rid of concurrent limits.

Comment: I'm not aware of any platform API so you would have to build your own counter if you wanted to go that way. Perhaps the [Queueable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm) mechanism would be of help where you send any work that might take more than 5 seconds to the queue.